# Output all filetypes into a file

Tags: filetype

```
echo getcompletion('', 'filetype')
```

The ex-command above lists all supported filetypes in vim. How can I output it into a file?

I tried these two ways but none worked.

```
echo getcompletion('', 'filetype') > /tmp/type.txt
!echo getcompletion('', 'filetype') > /tmp/type.txt
```

Comment: See `:help :redir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`writefile()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#writefile%28%29)

```
:call writefile(getcompletion('', 'filetype'), '/tmp/type.txt')
```

See [`:h functions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#functions)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be in a misunderstanding of how commands work in Vim versus how they work in a shell. The redirection operator you used (`>`) is available in the shell (assuming you're using bash or something similar), but it's not available in Vim's ex-command. Ex-commands are the commands available in Vim, the commands you execute in the command-line mode (see `:h command-line`).

- Your first command is wrong because Vim doesn't support `>` as redirection operator.
- Your second command is wrong because the shell (e.g., bash) doesn't know about the command `getcompletion`.

What you need to do is use `:h :redir` as /u/romainl suggested in the comments. Below is a handy custom Vim command, developed by romainl, that lets you redirect the output of a command to a buffer.

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=command Redir
      \ tabnew |
      \ setlocal nobuflisted buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe noswapfile |
      \ call setline(1, split(execute(<q-args>), "\n"))
```

Execute `:Redir echo getcompletion('', 'filetype')` and you'll get a buffer with the output of the command `:echo getcompletion('', 'filetype')`. You can then write the content of the buffer into a file with `:w <filename>`.

Answer (score 1):

Do as below:

```
:redir > /tmp/vim.output |echo getcompletion('', 'filetype')   | redir END
```